# How do I use Looper within requestLocationUpdates?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-looper

I am a beginner in Android development. I'm creating a small app that takes a picture after a device reaches a certain speed. However, one of the parameters of the requestLocationUpdates method (which of course is used to track the user’s location), requires a Looper in its third prameter. How would I create a looper? And where should it go? My requestLocationUpdates method currently looks like this: (I have null in place of a Looper)

```
 protected void requestUpdates() {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            MC.requestLocationUpdates(locRequest, mLocationCallback, null);
        }
    }
```

The Android dev site has advised to do something like this:

```
 class LooperThread extends Thread {
      public Handler mHandler;

      public void run() {
      Looper.prepare();

      mHandler = new Handler() {
          public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
              // process incoming messages here
          }
      };

      Looper.loop();
      }
  }
```

However, I still have no clue where to put this code, what to do with it once I put it in, or how I can use it within my MainActivity. Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: "_However, one of the parameters it requires is a Looper_" Getting a location does not require a Looper. Can you clarify what requires a Looper ?

Comment: The third parameter of the requestLocationUpdates method requires a Looper. I clarified it in the question as well. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: There are many versions of `requestLocationUpdates()`. You probably want to use the one that takes a `LocationListener` as a parameter. No `Looper` is needed.

Answer (score 2):

Create a looper by following code.

```
    HandlerThread handlerThread = new HandlerThread("MyHandlerThread");
    handlerThread.start();
    // Now get the Looper from the HandlerThread
    // NOTE: This call will block until the HandlerThread gets control and initializes its Looper
    Looper looper = handlerThread.getLooper();
```

and pass object of looper in requestLocationUpdates() as peramiter as following.

```
MC.requestLocationUpdates(locRequest, mLocationCallback, looper);
```

Answer (score 2):

If your callback does not access disk and is quick you can pass `null`.

Quoting [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html), you should pass

> a Looper object whose message queue will be used to implement the callback mechanism, or null to make callbacks on the calling thread

If you call `requestLocationUpdates` on the main thread and pass `null` as Looper, you'll receive callbacks on the main thread.

You can't access network from the main thread and you shouldn't perform any I/O operations on the main thread. Your UI would start lagging.

Answer (score 0):

As @Markus said in his comments, you will probably be required to pass `this` if your `Activity` has implemented `LocationListener` interface. That is the 3rd parameter you will need instead of a `Looper`.